# Angular 2 Cannot read property 'subscribe' of null for form field when using Validators.pattern

Tags: validation, typescript, angular2-forms

I working on Angular 2 reactive forms. I facing an issue in form field validation using Validators.pattern(). As soon as I start typing in the input field will get the exception `Cannot read property 'subscribe' of null`.

**TYPSCRIPT CODE**

```
createForm(){
    this.jobForm = this.fb.group({
        name: ['', Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/)],
        epType: ['ENDPOINT_TYPE_SBC', Validators.required],
        streams : this.fb.array([
            this.createStreamControls(),
        ]),
        channels:this.fb.array([
            this.createChannelControls(),
        ])
    });        
}
```

In 'name' attribute is validated against the pattern.

**HTML CODE**

```
 <div class="ui-grid-col-8 ">
      <input id="name" formControlName="name" pInputText class="width-60" />
                    <br>
      <small *ngIf="jobForm.controls.name.hasError('required') && jobForm.controls.name.touched" class="text-danger">Required</small>
      <small *ngIf="jobForm.controls.name.hasError('pattern') && jobForm.controls.name.touched" class="text-danger">Should be alpha-numeric without space</small>
 </div>
```

Trying to validate input field name.

EXCEPTION `Cannot read property 'subscribe' of null`

[Image showing Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nrw6w.png)

When I remove the Validators.pattern() from name attribute it works fine. I am not able to understand why it is failing here because I have used Validators.pattern() in the same form for other attributes and it works fine for them.

Comment: I think it should be `[ '', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/)])]`

Comment: Got it. @swaroop has highlighted the mistake I am doing. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Need to pass array of Validators in second argument of form group.

```
createForm(){
    this.jobForm = this.fb.group({
        name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/)]],
        epType: ['ENDPOINT_TYPE_SBC', [Validators.required]],
        streams : this.fb.array([
            this.createStreamControls(),
        ]),
        channels:this.fb.array([
            this.createChannelControls(),
        ])
    });        
}
```

Comment: Oh yes, my bad. I have been stuck for past 2 days with the issue. What a minor mistake do to you. :(
Thanks for the help :)